# How to trigger Required Field Validator

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

In Aspnet, how to trigger RequiredFieldValidator when a textbox is clicked?

Comment: edit my answer check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="javascript:trig();"></asp:TextBox>
```

javascript function

```
 function trig() {
        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= ValidatorID.ClientID %>'), true);
    }
```

Comment: I cannot get the value of that Requiredfieldvalidator through document.getelementbyid. It is in content page. Whether that is the problem? It is not working in my project. As it is working in a simple web page.

Comment: I think you have master page and that's why you are not getting proper ID, you can try using this...

Comment: document.getElementById('<%= yourValidatorID.ClientID %>')

Comment: Hi! Can u say me the javascript function for validatorDisable??

Answer (score 0):

In ajax control toolkit, there is a control called validator callout that will help you to do this, link here
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx

Comment: Thank u.. Actually My requirement is when clicking the box, that Validatorcallout should be called. For that I need to trigger it.